# Throw errors outside of promise

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, error-handling, promise

I have a function to log in a user which should return JSON.

```
const username = req.body.username;
const password = req.body.password;

if (!username) {
  throw new Error('Missing username');
}

if (!password) {
  throw new Error('Missing password');
}

User.findOne({ username, password }).then(user => {
  res.json({ user });
}).catch(err => {
  res.json({ err });
});
```

but then the errors for missing username or missing password are not returned in JSON.

I could change it to

```
const username = req.body.username;
const password = req.body.password;

if (!username) {
  res.json({ err: 'Missing username' });
}

if (!password) {
  res.json({ err: 'Missing password' });
}

User.findOne({ username, password }).then(user => {
  res.json({ user });
}).catch(err => {
  res.json({ err });
});
```

but it seems a little redundant.

Is the correct way to do it to encapsulate it in a promise?

Answer (score 2):

In your first solution, the thrown errors won't be handled, because you throw them outside of promise chain and without `try/catch` block. In your second solution you can get `cannot send headers after they sent` error, because the response can be sent twice (`username` is missing and `password` is missing).

So the one of the possible solutions here, is to create a promise chain (using `Promise.resolve()`) and validate parameters here:

```
function validateParams() {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;

  if (!username) {
    throw new Error('Missing username');
  }
  if (!password) {
    throw new Error('Missing password');
  }
  return { username, password };
}

Promise
  .resolve()
  .then(validateParams)
  .then(filter => User.findOne(filter))
  .then(user => res.json(user))
  .catch(err => res.json(err));
```

Comment: In your example you should include the call to `validateParams` :)

Comment: For the one reading this post, `.then(validateParams)` is equivalent to `.then(() => validateParams())`

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way would indeed be to encapsulate them in a promise to start your promise chain (with the `User.findOne` being inside the first `then`-block) - that way your current error handler catches them just fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your functions in a promise and handle it efficiently

```
function getRes(){  
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        const username = req.body.username;
        const password = req.body.password;

        if (!username) {
          reject(new Error('Missing username'));
        }

        if (!password) {
          reject(new Error('Missing password'));
        }

        resolve(User.findOne({ username, password }));
    });
}


getRes().then(function(result){
    res.json(result);
}).catch(function(err){
    res.json(err);
})
```

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: If you insist on using the `new Promise` constructor, either put the `User.findOne` promise in a `then` handler after it, or call `resolve(User.findOne(…))` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking the example from @alexmac and use es6 async feature:

```
function validateParams() {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;

  if (!username) {
    throw new Error('Missing username');
  }
  if (!password) {
    throw new Error('Missing password');
  }
  return { username, password };
}

async function resolver() {
    try {
        await resolve()
        let filter = validateParams()
        let user = await User.findOne(filter)
        await res.json(user)
    } catch (e) {
        await res.json(e)
    }
 }
```

and that would look more elegant by using an `if` instead of a `throw`:

```
async function(req, res) {
    const password = req.body.password
    const username = req.body.username
    let c = !password ? 'missing password' : 
                !username ? 'missing username' : null
    if (!c) {
       c = await User.findOne({ username, password })
    }
    await res.json(c)
}
```